# My Google Sheets script fails to send emails to Facebook group

Tags: email, google-sheets

I've written a very simple email script in a google sheet.

I have tested the script by using my own email address, but when I use a Facebook GRoup email address, the email bounces back from Facebook with a "POL-P6 http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=209.85.220.199#pol-m Message refused" message.

If I send the exact same email to the facebook group using gmail, rather than sheets, the email does not bounce, and is successfully posted.

I'm thinking that this is related to SPF and DKIM, but I'm not sure. I would appreciate any light on this.

Possible solutions I'm open to:

1) How to correctly set the SPF/DKIM to allow sheets to send the email.
2) A free email scheduler that will read the subject and body from a preconfigured file, and send the email on a future date
3) Other config that I've obviously overlooked.

I'm including the code that I'm using here:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 10;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var subject = row[1];       // Second column
    var message = row[2];       // Third column
    if(emailAddress != "")
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a sample from the sheet than I'm using:

```
Email                       Subject                             Message                                     Date        Time        Repeat
xxxx@groups.facebook.com    Check out all the other languages   https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxx/events  24/05/2016  16:00:00    Weekly
```

This is the error message I received from the Facebook server:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     xxxx@groups.facebook.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain groups.facebook.com by msgin.vvv.facebook.com. [66.220.159.18].

The error that the other server returned was:
554 5.7.1 POL-P6 http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=209.85.220.200#pol-m Message refused


----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:message-id:date:subject:from:to;
        bh=Tha9xrs+SsMgr1f6g/kqP/M1YN17QMZsR4wIogukb7M=;
        b=LW0tiMl7DvjD0DnUf/rU0YANFsVkSGZ2pPiBZwQMv00hK3JvRwjLXseDzhVddgBKY0
         1tfxnBuff7oGruFgdwf3rDddchU77CoVKCH6sQvBNU6d442lWdrqSpw8UBTuJUPrucz/
         kN+PKHe+5hPnl4tiPWnL3P9Nnw1Q/jPOkq5LCbVDHBK55nXaceBZRyp1B8474SrLN6AX
         MicGGoSK74BJsvKYdTubzjCLvpiC2LVj4kmRPz3YBuMQhPZrkNGUQ09WNXxeyDJ2mAdL
         TZv/K7ZA5eRNvhbdDWoA4QFdzfWEHejnBBj+yfGVSNUue2OrAD7hKlEDrupmm0sQHPLi
         RQKw==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:message-id:date:subject:from:to;
        bh=Tha9xrs+SsMgr1f6g/kqP/M1YN17QMZsR4wIogukb7M=;
        b=kC7S8oDRlE8ACX2wizIPkQbQlNjZaUXIn2jePw+/cmqoVYNAH7vwslcQPhrjjRkLlP
         FcztAQTp7blzosxqmxz1M9jijPnokphR6rH1t17l9V7hcNjX92xc2PRRkuSDauIt6OjK
         FtTJgwDjQhz0ilHMqntJIVzjA+J964eEH6m1eLceTKAcz+5+ukcUSg/LHVXOe3IS34SE
         M5CHm5jkYWQxL6vLJYNfPbE+6tMLwvLmkYkGmPtVD0Sxghn1IYtinHpaC/e5n8MA7REe
         V1gI+Fl6ki3CgVLLOCKcYs4dhYIVG4Bk6TkspMkrbWJwLuPsWCHBVoDNXa26eS2nfkzu
         RkDA==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tKUQtlhdFcKfFUpHkCdvkXIiAo1Qny6c/VPOHziRvjSsAUUrZP+GpsNS0iKSW0zfa7dbxPsOHZpoicerg==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.129.71.213 with SMTP id u204mr3993391ywa.51.1464114280537;
 Tue, 24 May 2016 11:24:40 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <001a114c6ec09a28e405339aab2a@google.com>
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 18:24:40 +0000
Subject: Check out all the other languages
From: mmmmm@gmail.com
To: xxxx@groups.facebook.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes

https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx/events
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try sending a simple text-only message, without a link? Facebook _could_ be blocking all Google Apps Script servers to fight spammers. [You're not the first to complain about such errors](https://www.google.com/search?q=554+5.7.1+POL-P6).

Comment: Well, I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: Ok. So I removed the link, and still no luck. Using plain text content, the message is still blocked. I'll report the problem to FAcebook directly to see if they can help also.

Comment: So, after reporting the problem to Facebook, the emails began arriving to the group page. So, it wasn't the content, but something blocked on FB's side. Problem solved. Good luck to anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after reporting the problem to Facebook, the emails began arriving to the group page. So, it wasn't the content, but something blocked on FB's side. Problem solved. Good luck to anyone who has the same problem.